# What does "self lit" mean, and why is it a good thing?

Tags: light, terminology

I've seen some artists post scenes they describe as "self lit" [[1](https://sketchfab.com/models/9203c5e0ab5a4508b76518f443714b45)],[[2](https://sketchfab.com/models/69be107ca5234ca8a9fcff6ba6851e9e)]. What does this mean, and why is it desirable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It refers to models that already have the lights prebaked using lightmaps or pre-render all the model and bake it into a texture. Both are useful for real-time visualization of static scenes, since it can show photorrealistic results without have to render everything everytime. You can get more information about in the links below:

Lightmap: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightmap

Baking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU